# Blocking/disabling JavaFX 2 WebView right click

Tags: webview, javafx, javafx-2

I'm looking for a way to block/disable right click in javafx.scene.web.WebView. To be more specific I don't want the context menu to show up on right click. I'm new to the technology and can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for the record, it is implemented in JavaFX 2.2. See documentation for [setContextMenuEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#setContextMenuEnabled(boolean)) (JavaFX 2) and [setContextMenuEnabled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#setContextMenuEnabled-boolean-) (JavaFX 8)

Comment: This is recommended solution since JavaFX 2.2, but if somehow you are using JavaFX 2.0 or 2.1 you will have to take the EventDispatcher approach described below.

Comment: `<WebView fx:id="webViewId" contextMenuEnabled="false"` in the FXML doesn't work yet, so indeed use this call in the controller. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633202/javafx-webview-method-contextmenuenabled-could-not-be-found-warning)

Answer (score 5):

I've came up with working, but ugly, inelegant and, I'd say, partisan solution, which I don't really like, but actually I have no (or just can't find) other way out.

It includes modifying EventDispatcher of WebView.

So my implementation of EventDispatcher needs a reference to original WebView EventDispatcher and looks like that:

```
public class MyEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {

private EventDispatcher originalDispatcher;

public MyEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher originalDispatcher) {
    this.originalDispatcher = originalDispatcher;
}

@Override
public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
    if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
        MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
        if (MouseButton.SECONDARY == mouseEvent.getButton()) {
            mouseEvent.consume();
        }
    }
    return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
}
}
```

Everytime event is dispatched it goes through our dispatcher and I check if it's right click. If it is I just consume it and proceed further.

To make it work you have to use WebView like that:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = webView.getEventDispatcher();
webView.setEventDispatcher(new MyEventDispatcher(originalDispatcher));
```

Every comment, clue and so on are appreciated.

Comment: good one. You also may need to consume "context menu" keyboard button event and Ctrl-Right Click for Mac.

Comment: In my application I did as you said. I blocked every CTRL combination. Although here I just wanted to present the idea.

Answer (score 4):

With JavaFX 2.2+ it's now possible to set WebView's ContextMenuEnabled to false:

```
webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
```

[WebView API Doc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#setContextMenuEnabled(boolean))

Comment: I've asked this question in march 2012. Only JavaFX 2.0 was avaible and there was no setContextMenuEnabled method back then.

Answer (score 3):

You can style context menus away using the following css.

```
.context-menu     { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
.menu-item        { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
.menu-item .label { -fx-text-fill: transparent; }
.menu-item:show-mnemonics .mnemonic-underline { -fx-stroke: -transparent; }
```

This will make all context menus and menu items transparent.  I'm not sure of the css selector you could use to make this only apply to WebView context menus.  If you don't have other menus in your application, that may not be a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with js (`jquery` used)

```
$(document).ready( function() { document.oncontextmenu = function() { return false } } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not yet possible. There is a feature request for that, which you may want to track: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15684

Comment: That's absolutely horrific news. Will that be added to 2.1 release? Is there at least a way to translate those context menus?

Comment: The Jira feature is now implemented and available in the [JavaFX 2.2 developer preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) and will be included in the JavaFX 2.2 (jdk7u6) release.

Answer (score 1):

This will will remove the context menu for the entire stage:

```
primaryStage.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            event.consume();
        }

    }
});
```